# Remote jobs should show map with accepted timezones highlighted

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs, timezone

When a remote job is restricted to some time zone, you need to check if your country falls within the specified time zone (time zone is usually specified in GMT).

It would be nice to have a small map with the accepted timezones highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry! This is not currently something we're looking to implement.

Comment: That's a shame.  I've been burned on this before when helping a near-graduate look for internships, but the only ones that were available were in Germany (and we're in the US Midwest).